# 'For' loop in C loops endlessly

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I know this has been asked before, but I've been unable to find an answer I can apply to my case.

I've been unable to get this For loop to end. I'm sure it's something simple, can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  /* variable definition: */
  char StudentName[100];
  float ExamValue, Sum, Avg;
  int students, exams;
  int Total_Students;

    printf("Enter total number of students: \n");
    scanf("%d", &Total_Students);

   // Loop through x students
  for (students = Total_Students; students++;)
  {
     // reset Sum to 0
     Sum =0.0;  
     printf("Enter Student Name \n");
     scanf("%s", StudentName); 

     // Nested Loop for Exams
    for (exams=0; exams < 3; exams++)
    {
        printf ("Enter exam grade: \n");
        scanf("%f", &ExamValue);
        Sum += ExamValue;
    }   
    Avg = Sum/3.0;
    printf( "Average for %s is %f\n",StudentName,Avg);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `for (students = Total_Students; students++;)` supposed to do? You probably want something like `for (students = 0; students < Total_Students;  students ++)` there, no?

Comment: Now is a good time to learn about debuggers.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This code can solve your problem.
you should make condition like this, set the start, end point accurately

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
/* variable definition: */
char StudentName[100];
float ExamValue, Sum, Avg;
int students, exams;
int Total_Students;

printf("Enter total number of students: \n");
scanf_s("%d", &Total_Students);

// Loop through x students
// you should make condition like this, set the start, end point accurately
for ( students = Total_Students; students>0; students--)
{
    // reset Sum to 0
    Sum = 0.0;
    printf("Enter Student Name : \n");
    scanf_s("%s", StudentName,sizeof(StudentName));
    getchar();

    // Nested Loop for Exams
    for (exams = 0; exams < 3; exams++)
    {
        printf("Enter exam grade: \n");
        scanf_s("%f", &ExamValue);
        Sum += ExamValue;
    }
    Avg = Sum / 3.0;
    printf("Average for %s is %f\n", StudentName, Avg);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why the original code was misbehaving.

Comment: There are only two corrections in the code @Matthieu 
1. for ( students = Total_Students; students>0; students--)
-> make students to Total and iterate with students--

2.  scanf_s("%s", StudentName,sizeof(StudentName));
-> it can make no error with String

Comment: I know. You just need to explicitely say *which ones* and *why* so your answer can make sense. Right now it's just a piece of code saying "now go and figure yourself"...

Comment: Don't edit the comment, edit your answer to include your explanation.

Comment: ok bro, now cool?

Comment: Thank you Sang Won, setting Student-- was the solution. So, if I understand the logic behind it, setting Student_number sets the start point, and student-- will count it down to the zero which is an automatic end point by default.

Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: Yes, your logic is right. if you use visual studio for C programming, press F10 to debug your code. It will make you understand your code more easily.

Comment: I'm currently just using Ideone.com, which leaves a lot to be desired. Do you have any suggestions for free compilers/debuggers?

Comment: If your OS is Window, Visual studio is the best way to procedural programming as far as I concerned.

Comment: @ShamrockShake use Eclipse CDT or MS Code/Visual Studio. A lot is learnt by step-by-step debugging. SangWon no, there is still no explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In the outer loop that is expected to loop over x students is actually starting from x students and goes to infinity. You should start it from zero and bound it by "Total Students".

Comment: It doesn't "go to infinity" but over...